# XCode breakpoint is not working in a current line. Its stops on threat instead of current line

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, breakpoints

I have a XCode 6.4 and from last week its behave like a strange. When I applied any breakpoint on it, then it is not stopped at current line instead it stops in thread. I tried to uninstall it and install XCode
6.3.1 but nothing happens. Then again I install latest version of XCode i.e. 6.4, but still no progress. I am sharing you some image to understand it better.

Please see the images on following link

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try stopping it on an actual line of code, not a comment.

Comment: Thats not the cause here. It should break within the function still. Just at the end of it

Comment: Thanks @bhavin for the steps...it is now working for current line :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just goto `debug->debug workflow` and **uncheck** `always show disassembly`

[image]